# How to upload sitemap.xml through app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sitemap

I am using google app engine to host my website. I tried to upload sitemap.xml, but when I open the link i.e., www.example.com/sitemap.xml it shows `Oops! This link appears to be broken.`. I don't know the reason for this. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the content of my app.yaml file

```
application: mywebsite
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))



- url: .*
  script: main.py

- url: /icon\.ico
  static_files: icon.ico
  upload: icon.ico

- url: /sitemap.xml    
  static_files: static/sitemap.xml
  upload: static/sitemap.xml

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Required_Elements), "Patterns are evaluated in the order they appear in the app.yaml, from top to bottom. The first mapping whose pattern matches the URL is the one used to handle the request.".

You should try moving the catch all handler (url: .*) to the end of the file.

Comment: In my app, I don't even need to include `- url: /sitemap.xml` handler in yaml file. It is cathed up by `- url: .*`